# Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010 sending message to self

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

I have a customer who is copying herself on e-mails that she sends periodically.  If she selects her mail address from the GAL it works fine, but if she types her smtp e-mail address in the cc line, it comes back as undeliverable, not a valid e-mail address.  It is not in the cache and adding from the GAL does not add it back into the cache.  It used to work fine.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have her delete her autocomplete cache:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287623

There is most likely an entry for her own email in the cache that resolves an incorrect address or LegacyExchangeDN/x500 address. Does the NDR include an "IMCEAEX-" in it?